# jquery object does not work as a global variable

Tags: jquery

This is a very simplified version of the code to explain my issue.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="enableDisableBox" id="radioDisable" checked="checked" />
Disable
<br />
<input type="radio" name="enableDisableBox" id="radioEnable" />
Enable
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtUserInput" disabled="disabled" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var txtInputObj2 = $("#txtUserInput");

function init1() {
    var txtInputObj1 = $("#txtUserInput");
    $("input[name='enableDisableBox']:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#radioEnable").attr("checked"))
            txtInputObj1.removeAttr("disabled").focus();
        else
            txtInputObj1.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
}

function init2() {
    $("input[name='enableDisableBox']:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#radioEnable").attr("checked"))
            txtInputObj2.removeAttr("disabled").focus();
        else
            txtInputObj2.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init1();
    //init2();
});
```

If I run the init2 function, it does not give me any errors, but does not enable or disable my textbox either.

if you notice, txtInputObj1 is defined within the init1 function, and txtInputObj2 is defined as a global variable.

Any suggestions on how to make a jQuery selector object global?

Comment: You are doing `$("#txtUserInput")` *before* the DOM is ready.  The element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Where did you declare  your jquery?  I have seen some people delcaring jQuery in the bottom of the html script (usually before `</body>`.  I usually practice that approach for all of my javascript files, except for jQuery as I always used it in my `<head>`.  This gave me the ability to have jQuery as global.

Comment: it is defined within the head section

Comment: I think this could be cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/fk72A/ `$('input[name=enableDisableBox]').on('change', function() {
    $('#txtUserInput').prop("disabled", $(this).val() === 'false').focus();
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var txtInputObj2 = $("#txtUserInput");` runs outside the DOM ready handler, so the element is not available at that time, otherwise it would have worked.

**EDIT:**

In my opinion it's a bad idea, but this is how you'd do what you're asking for.
Declare the variable first, or declare it as global, and set the value when the DOM is ready

```
var txtInputObj2;

function init2() {
    $("input[name='enableDisableBox']:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#radioEnable").attr("checked"))
            txtInputObj2.removeAttr("disabled").focus();
        else
            txtInputObj2.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    txtInputObj2 = $("#txtUserInput");

    // could also do window.txtInputObj2 without the previous decleration

    init1();
    init2();
});
```

Comment: because I want to use the same jQuery object within another function in the same js file. Once I have the object selected, why should i need to select it again?

Comment: @TK1 - Basically, if you need an element as a global variable, in many cases you're doing something wrong, but anyway, added an answer that does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: ok, this worked for me ... but could you please elaborate why this is a bad idea? I'm learning as I go!

Comment: I want this variable as a global because I will be accessing this by different functions within the same .js file. this js file is only loaded by a specific page and is only applicable to that page.

Comment: You should generally try to avoid polluting the global namespace, but it's not like it won't work, it will work just fine this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cuwor/5/edit)**
Why not something like:

```
// function outside DOM ready
function init() {
  $(":radio[name='enableDisableBox']").change(function () {
        $('#txtUserInput').prop('disabled', this.id=="radioDisable").focus();
  });
}

$(function() { // DOM IS NOW READY

    init();  // Function called inside DOM ready so all fine!
    // OTHER CODE HERE

});
```

---

If you want to create a reusable `var` to store your element you could do:

```
// function outside DOM ready
function init( elemSelector ) { // NOTE the elemSelector argument!
  $(":radio[name='enableDisableBox']").change(function () {
        elemSelector.prop('disabled', this.id=="radioDisable").focus();
  });
}

$(function() { // DOM IS NOW READY
    var myInput = $('#txtUserInput'); // Reusable element variable
    init( myInput );  // send your var as an argument to your fn.
    // OTHER CODE HERE
    // Reuse myInput variable as your element selector if needed like:
    // myInput.blur();   
});
```

Comment: I want to create a global variable, which I can use within the same js file in a different function as well ... unfortunately, this solution will not work for me.

Comment: @TK1 edited my answer for a muuuuch simpler solution.

Comment: @TK1 the main goal is to make sure your jQuery elements selectors like i.e: `$('#someElement')` are read inside an DOM ready function like `$(function(){ /* here */ });` or you need to call an external function that has your selectors insite it! The issue mostly happens when you use `<script>` tags in `<head>` while the DOM is not yet parsed by JS which means your elements are not *in memory / ready* to be manipulated. Another way to make sure the Document is ready (suggestion!) is to always put your `<script>` tags before the closing `</body>` tag.